# How to view Microsoft forum posts without login

Tags: microsoft-community

I have the following [Microsoft forum link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/166b9d06-a0d2-46c0-a9c9-dfb980ef31c0/timed-out-while-trying-to-connect-to-the-virtual-machine?forum=winserverhyperv) and I intend to read it.

When I click, it *redirects* me to a login page. **The login page can't be skipped**, I can only register.

[image]

I cleared all the cookies.

What should I do? I think those posts are Public and it normally opens and Works when someone tries to read a post (why does Edge automatically modifiy the capitalization of Public and Works?).

Comment: *I think those posts are Public and it normally opens and Works when someone tries to read a post* That may be your opinion, but if Microsoft decides to put these pages behind a login, there is nothing you can do.

Comment: @JanDoggen Can you open the thread without login?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it was pointed out in this [article](https://www.koskila.net/how-to-log-in-to-microsofts-websites-msdn-forums-azure-portal-sharepoint-online-when-you-get-a-bad-request-error/), Microsoft services tend to *mismatch cookies* and it causes irregular behavior.

It is recommended to **delete relevant cookies** that are set on the login screen and it solves the issue.